# Space constraint in scheduling problem

Tags: constraint, scheduling

I'm studying an MIP model with a scheduling problem and I'm wondering if the space constraint is correct.

If there is space in the factory at that time, the block can be processed, where

- $i$ is the block number
- $S_i$, $C_i$ and $P_i$ are the strat time, completion time and processing time of block $i$ respectively
- $y_{i,j,f}=\begin{cases}1\quad\text{if}\,i\,\text{process before}\,j\,\text{at factory}\,f\\0\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
- $y_{i,f}=\begin{cases}1\quad\text{if}\,i\,\text{process at factory}\,f\\0\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
- $M$ is a big number
- $sp_i$ is the required space of block $i$
- $c_{f,t}$ is the available space of factory $f$ at time $t$

\begin{align}S_i -M(1-y_{i,j,f}) &\le S_j\quad\forall i,j,f\\S_i + P_i &= C_i\quad \forall i\end{align}

The space constraint is
$$sp_i \cdot y_{i,f} \le c_{f,t}\quad\forall i,j\quad\text{and}\quad t=S_i,\cdots,C_i.$$

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you say please, what exactly do you mean by "space constrain"? What the scheduling problem you have faced and are going to solve using MIP? It sounds like a material handling problem instead of the detailed schedule problem.

Comment: Space constraint refers to the space where blocks can be operated. 
The block assembly plant is dealing with a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Would you see some layout optimization model? I hope [this](https://www.amazon.com/Facilities-Design-Sunderesh-S-Heragu/dp/1498732895) link would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your space constraint is incorrect. There are multiple problems, including the fact that the range of the index $t$ depends on variables $S_i$ and $C_i$. Note that your current space constraint would not stop two jobs from using the same capacity simultaneously. (Your precedence constraint forces one job to start before another, but does not force the second job to wait until the first job has completed.) Also, your precedence constraint should be $\le$, not $\lt$.

Comment: Thanks for you,

Comment: May I ask one more question?
Can index t be modeled without dependence on S and C?

Comment: Assuming $c_{f,t}$ is a parameter, what you can do is create one constraint for each $t$ in the planning horizon. That constraint sums up the space utilization of all blocks $i$ such that $y_{i,f}=1$ and $S_i \le t \le C_i$, and forces the total not to exceed $c_{f,t}$. The left side can be linearized, although it's a bit complicated. Similar questions about linearizing conditional expressions have been asked and answered on this site.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much

Comment: I've been thinking about it for a few days, but I have no idea. If you don't mind, could you express it in a formula?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably not in a comment, particularly since it would require additional variables and constraints. Among other things, I think you need to change $S_i$ into a collection of binary variables (for instance, $S_{it}=1$ if and only if block $i$ starts at time $t$, or maybe $S_{ift}=1$ if and only if block $i$ starts at time $t$ at factory $j$), and similarly with $C_i$. If you look through other questions on this site tagged scheduling, you'll likely find examples that would provide a starting point.

Comment: I'll think about it. Thanks

Comment: The comment was too long, so I wrote a new post.If you don't mind, could you look at it again? https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/resource-constraint-with-mip-model